# Cronjob error - s3cmd - No such file or directory

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, cron, bitnami, s3cmd

I am in the process of setting up a wordpress/woocommerce site on AWS with a CloudFront CDN however I am unable to get the cronjob push to S3 working.

I am using the stock bitnami wordpress AMI and have installed s3cmd. Using s3cmd I have been able to transfer (put) files to the S3 bucket successfully however I am unsuccessful in getting the cronjob working.

I am trying to push changes every five mins:

```
*/5 **** bitnami /usr/share/s3cmd sync -r --delete-removed --add header "Cache-Control:max-age=31536000" /opts/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content s3://www.example.com
```

Which returns:

> -bash: */5: No such file or directory

I could be off it seems like I am off in my cron script as the following code is working:

```
s3cmd put -r --add header "Cache-Control:max-age=31536000" /opts/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content s3://www.example.com
```

I've confirmed that the directories exist and the s3 IAM permissions are valid.

Comment: Do you have a backtick at the beginning of the line?

Comment: @BenjaminW. No backtick in the code. Copy and paste error on my side

Comment: @MarkB I believe I am using the full path. When I log into the SFTP (filezilla, username: bitnami Logon Type: Keyfile) that's the path I use to get to what I believe is the correct s3cmd directory. Am I missing something?

Comment: It seems to try to run the whole cron entry as a command. Where exactly do you put this line?

Comment: Post whatever you see in `crontab -e`

Comment: @BenjaminW. I connect directly to the server using Putty and enter it into the command line using a similar process to the working s3cmd put command

Comment: What's the output of `crontab -l`?

Comment: Do you get any output? What do you see if you redirect output to a log file?

Comment: Oh wait, that seems to be your output above. Hmmm.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Could the issue be related to any one of the following 3 reasons? 1) /usr/share/s3cmd is the wrong path to use, 2) need to use root over bitnami user name or 3) when attempting with root it could be the --configure (setup on bitnami user) are not copied over to root user. Any ideas how to isolate at test?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152584/discussion-between-benjamin-w-and-tjrburgess).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out with the help of a few people that know their stuff...

Came down to a missing /

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/s3cmd sync -r --delete-removed --add-header "Cache-Control:max-age=31536000" /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/ s3://www.example.com/
```